# Why can the forbidden corridor on the third floor be unlocked by simply using Alohomora?

Tags: harry-potter

If that corridor's just so important and held a very dangerous beast, why would they let it be opened just by simply casting an Alohomora?

Comment: Hogwarts under Dumbledore (as opposed to the modern muggle world) isnt really foolproof. You usually get one warning, if you fail to listen. ..oh well..good luck.

Comment: The real question is: Why teach students how to open locked doors ? The muggles don't learn lockpicking at school. Those doors are locked for a reason.

Comment: @atayenel so you wont have to use keys like a muggle. It's a simple charm probably everyone knows and uses to lock and unlock doors to indicate 'closed'. In addition there are various more secure levels of protection: the fidelius charm, age etc. wards, passwords if you really want to restrict access to certain groups. A locked door is the easiest, less secure solution. Like MAC filtering.

Answer (score 3):

The door is there for the students.

It's forbidden, move away.

Try to open it ? It's locked, move away.

Cracked it with a spell ? Here is a giant angry three-headed dog, don't forget to change your pants.

The door's purpose is only to block most students avoid them being hurt if they got curious, the real protections being behind it.

Comment: If they got curious, all the students had to do was to use a simple spell to open the door, and as a consequence face the wrath of a vicious three-headed dog. So how is the door's purpose to protect the students from being hurt "if they got curious"?

Comment: @AnyaMae Because it required to be curious and willing to break an explicit instruction.And in the end, I guess it boiled down to JKR deciding that only the main characters would open it.